# change y axis scale in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to replicate a plot drawn by graphpad in r
but I have a problem changing the y axis
here is an example data and my plot codes:

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- data.frame(names = rep(factor(LETTERS[1:3])),
                   values = c(0.001, 0.02 ,0.95),
                   group = rep("A",3))


ggplot(data,
       aes(x = group,
           y = values,
           fill = names)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position='stack') +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0.001,0.01,0.1,1), labels=c(0.001,0.01,0.1,1))
```

the result of my code is on top but I want to plot it like the image on the bottom.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the values to their logs, then add a constant that makes all the log values greater than 0. Then re-label the axis appropriately:

```r
data2 <- data %>% 
  mutate(logvalues = log10(values) - min(log10(0.0001)))

ggplot(data2[order(-data2$logvalues),], 
         aes(x = group, y = logvalues, fill = names)) + 
  geom_col(position = 'identity') +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 0:4, labels = ~ 10^(.x-4))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as you can see C has the biggest value but in your plot is the smallest part. I think it's because scale_y_log10() transforms the data in the log10 scale. Is there a way to just change the y axis without transforming the data?

Comment: @RezaKhayami I see what you mean. Check out my update. Is that what you're looking for?